# Java Char цикл по массиву

Tags: java

Есть char массив.Как в нем проверить, есть ли в нём какой-то символ?

```
 char[] abc = {1,2,3,4,t,6,7};
for(int i=0; i<+abc.length; i++)
{
   if(abc[i] == t) System.out.println("Yes");
}
```

И ещё можно ли как-то в массив char записать спец. символ ( #, @, *)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Символьные литералы в Java записываются в одинарных кавычках.
    '#', '@', '*', 't'